# What is the correct terminology for a string of binary bytes representing a value?

Tags: string, binary, integer, hex, byte

What is the correct terminology for a string of binary bytes representing a value?

For example, the number (decimal) **16,639**

When I try to look up converting an integer to *binary*, I get algorithms to produce this output string:

"100000011111111"

When I try to look up converting an integer to *hex*, I get algorithms to produce this output string:

"40FF"

What I'm really looking for is, to (when decoded with ISO-8859-1) produce this:

"@ÿ"

So what would I call that, Integer to ______ conversion?

Answer (score 0):

One name for that is "base 256 encoding". It maps each byte to its naive character representation.